# Make dynamic list according to another list

Tags: javascript

I have a list with below structure

> [{name:A,key:1},{name:B,key:2},{name:C,key:3}]

I want to create a list with this structure but reverse data between name and key :

> [{name:1,key:A},{name:2,key:B},{name:3,key:C}]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just map it

```
const data1 = [{name:"A",key:1},{name:"B",key:2},{name:"C",key:3}];

const data2 = data1.map(data=>{
    // if statement
 return {key: data.name, name: data.key}
});
```

Comment: Zavaliii :  how can i use if in it for ex if(data.key!=1) ?

Comment: I use it but items that against if (else) is undefined